# Django Mysql Database Configuration and Security

Tags: mysql, django, unix-socket

Is there a way to **access a MySQL database from** **Django without explicitly providing credentials** such as USERNAME, DATABASE NAME, and PASSWORD? I've explored methods like using dotenv or storing credentials in separate files, but I'm interested in alternatives. Are there approaches such as utilising Unix sockets or other methods to achieve this? Could someone provide an example of how to implement such a solution?

Comment: How you authenticate to mysql depends on what authentication plugins are installed on your mysql server. As far as I know, the free community editions come with password authentication only. You need to buy commercial version of mysql that has integrated windows and kerberos authentication plugins. Or you need to implement your own authentication plugin. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/authentication-plugins.html